# MS Access: add some text at the bottom of the continuous form

Tags: ms-access

In my ms access project, I need to add some text at the bottom of the continuous form. I can not add the text as footer, because footer always stick to the window and it doesn't scroll with the continuous form. I need the text only to show if the user scroll down at the bottom of the form. How can I do this?

Comment: AFAIK there's no way... the rows in a continuous form are all copies of the template row, and the number of rows is generated by the row source of the form

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means perfect, but it may have possibilities for you. Unfortunately, it relies on the user selecting a record:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
''The form I used for testing displayed only three records
If Me.CurrentRecord >= Me.Recordset.RecordCount - 1 Then
    Me.FormFooter.Visible = True
Else
    Me.FormFooter.Visible = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice idea but rather than selecting the record, can we make it on scrolling? Suppose, if user scroll down to last record or last 5 record, I will show the footer. Is there any way to check which record the user is scrolling?